Get the ARIMA and ETS parameters from hts2 package: hierarchical and grouped time-series
I'm currently working on my first time series project in R and using the hts2 package to make predictions with ARIMA and ETS models. Since I am still new to the hts package, I'm having trouble finding the parameters of the ARIMA and ETS models used, particularly for the aggregated ARIMA model.
I would like to extract these parameters so that I can plot specific ARIMA functions. Can anyone guide me on how to retrieve the parameters of the aggregated ARIMA model in the hts2 package?
I have successfully prepared my dataset and completed predictions using the hts2 package in R. Below is the specific part of my forecast:
final <- tsib_data %>% 
  aggregate_key(adm * sex * age, value = sum(value)) %>%
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(value),
    ets = ETS(value)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    arima_mint = min_trace(arima),
    ets_mint = min_trace(ets)
  ) %>%
  forecast(h = 21) 

I would like to access the details for both ARIMA and ETS models applied to each group in the hierarchy.

Coefficients from models in fable can be obtained using tidy().
